# Compare values with decimal

Tags: xslt

I need to compare the values being returned in my xml. If the value is 0.00 then do 'this' else 'do this'. I'm getting a error when I test my code.

error:
Unable to generate the XML document using the provided XML/XSL input. Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation

Site using to test:
https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html

Here is the XML:

```
<cst>
  <cli>
    <cli_contact_person_name>a customer service representative</cli_contact_person_name>
    <cli_phone_number>312-422-3236</cli_phone_number>
    <cli_contact_phone_ext>312-422-3236</cli_contact_phone_ext>
    <cli_email_address>aha-orders@pbd.com</cli_email_address>
  </cli>
    <inv>
      <cli_contact_person_name>a customer service representative</cli_contact_person_name>
      <cli_phone_number>312-422-3236</cli_phone_number>
      <cli_contact_phone_ext>312-422-3236</cli_contact_phone_ext>
      <cli_email_address>aha-orders@pbd.com</cli_email_address>
      <AHABU>AHA</AHABU>
      <cst_key>D387A106-0E7C-4201-A9DD-1B0615191D18</cst_key>
      <inv_key>31F2FD83-0A06-49CC-A424-84054EF15D8F</inv_key>
      <inv_code_cp>131961</inv_code_cp>
      <inv_trx_date>01/05/2010</inv_trx_date>
      <inv_total>150.00</inv_total>
      <inv_pyd_date>01/05/2010</inv_pyd_date>
      <inv_paid>125.00</inv_paid>
      <inv_balance>25.00</inv_balance>
    </inv>
  </invs>
</cst>
```

Here is the XSL code:

```
<!--Paid-->
    <div class="orderhistory-subcontainer2 orderhistory-hide-1">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="inv_balance=0.00">
                <xsl:value-of select="inv_pyd_date" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    <!--<xsl:value-of select="inv_pyd_date" />-->
    </div>
```

Also tried this:

```
<!--Paid-->
<div class="orderhistory-subcontainer2 orderhistory-hide-1">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test = "format-number(inv_balance, '0.00') = number(0.00)">
            <xsl:value-of select="inv_pyd_date" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
<!--<xsl:value-of select="inv_pyd_date" />-->
```

The issue is my syntax I think in here:

or at least i thought that was the original issue. Not sure whats the issue now

Update: 
tried this as well stll not working with same error:

```
 <xsl:when test = "format-number(inv_balance, '#.00') = number(0.00)">
```

Update:
I found the error:

```
<xsl:value-of select="" />
```

Comment: Please state the exact error message and consider to show minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is:

```
 <xsl:when test="inv_balance=0">
```

This will convert the string "0.00" to a number and compare it to the number 0:

> if at least one object to be compared is a number, then each object to be compared is converted to a number as if by applying the number function.
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans

Comment: Thanks. I think I tried this at first but I must of did something wrong. I hate xsl ugg anyway thank you very much for helping.